# basic differential question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need guidance on this problem. Could someone lead me in a direction of how I should go about doing this question. Is there some sort of proof involved in this question? No need to solve the question just some guidance would be good.

show that $f′(−x)=f′(x)$ for all x

EDIT:

f is a differentiable odd function then f(prime) is an even function

Comment: There need to be more assumptions on $f$ for that to be true; a simple counterexample is $f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: I would guess he wants $f(x)$ to be an odd function.

Comment: f is a differentiable odd function while f(prime) is an even function

Comment: If $f(x)$ is an odd function, $f(-x) = -f(x)$ by definition, what can you do to both sides of the equation to make it look like $f^{\prime}(-x) = f^{\prime}(x)$?

Comment: humm @JessicaK ... can I use the definition of derivative?

Comment: You can always use the definition, but I would just use the chain rule.

Comment: humm chain rule, how would that work? I mean how would I use the chain rule in this circumstance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f(x)$ is an odd function, then by definition

$$f(-x) = -f(x).$$

Since $f$ is differentiable, apply the derivative to both sides and use the chain rule

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(-x) = \frac{d}{dx}-f(x)$$

or
$$-f^{\prime}(-x) = -f^{\prime}(x)$$

multiplying by -1 gives you the desired result.

Comment: sorry for my lack of understanding in mathematical concepts... but I cannot understand how we can use the chain rule in this case :  d/dx f(−x)= d/dx −f(x)

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}f(-x) = f^{\prime}(-x)* \frac{d}{dx}(-x) = -f^{\prime}(-x)$ by the chain rule.

Comment: ahh I see now... and now I understand if f(-x) = -f(x) ... the derivative which is an even function should look like its predecessor the odd function... tricky question :p ... but Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This statement is not true. A function $f$ must have additional conditions. Assume that $f$ has some conditions. You can proof directly from the definition of derivative:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$